# ¿A que se podría deber la detención de mi aplicación para android? "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo poco tiempo dedicándome a la programación en android y he estado tratando de desarrollar una aplicación de un formulario con Sliding Tabs, encontré un código que he tratado de probar para darme una idea pero me devuelve los siguientes errores:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager, PID: 2506
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager/com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager/com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.PhotosActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager/com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.PhotosActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:2210)
                  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:286)
                  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:724)
                  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:388)
                  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:222)
                  at com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Lo que pude identificar fue que no puede encontrar el activity "PhotosActivity" pero si lo tengo declarado en el manifest y otra en esta parte del codigo Java:

```
 // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(gralspec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(cablespec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(fibrespec); // Adding videos tab
```

Realmente no comprendo a que se deban estos errores y agradecería mucho la ayuda que me pudieran brindar para identificar el por que. De antemano muchas gracias por su atención.

Aqui esta mi archivo Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<!--  Songs Activity -->
     <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" />

<!--  Videos Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".VideosActivity" />

<!--  Photos Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".PhotosActivity" />
```

Y mi archivo Java:

```
    package com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabHost.TabSpec gralspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("General");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        gralspec.setIndicator("General", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_general_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        gralspec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabHost.TabSpec cablespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Cableado");
        cablespec.setIndicator("Cableado", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_structure_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        cablespec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabHost.TabSpec fibrespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fibra");
        fibrespec.setIndicator("Fibra", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_fiber_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        fibrespec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(gralspec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(cablespec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(fibrespec); // Adding videos tab
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonathan, el registro de tus activities debe ser dentro de <application>, ese es el problema.

Comment: @Elenasys Que descuido el mio, no me había percatado de eso, ya funciona todo perfectamente, agradezco su atención.

Comment: Las activities siempre van declaradas dentro de <application.. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tienes declarado tu Activity fuera de la etiqueta application

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<!--  Photos Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".PhotosActivity" />


</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste añadir la actividad al Manifest.xml? algo asi `<activity android:name=".PhotosActivity" />` Si pudieras subir la clase y el manifest ayudaria mucho para ayudate a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que declares una activity que no hayas creado mediante el IDE, tienes que agregarla al manifest.

Si te fijas en la primera línea del error, al final te pregunta si has declarado tu activity en el. Manifest.

Los errores de Android suelen ser llenos de texto, pero cono leer bien se encuentra la solución fácilmente.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje definido en el LogCat indica el problema, no se encuentra la activity `com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.PhotosActivity` ya que no esta declarada dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager/com.example.jonathanraymundo.pager.PhotosActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

En ocasiones agregamos Activity a nuestros proyectos pero estas no se registran automáticamente en el AndroidManifest.xml, **agrega la actividad dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que quede registrada en tu aplicacion.**

```
  <application
     ...
      ...
      <activity android:name=".PhotosActivity"/>
  </application>
```

---

Actualización:
Revisando tu `AndroidManifest.xml` tienes tus Activities declaradas afuera de **`<application>`**, deben estar contenidas dentro:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--  Songs Activity -->
         <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" />

    <!--  Videos Activity -->
            <activity android:name=".VideosActivity" />

    <!--  Photos Activity -->
            <activity android:name=".PhotosActivity" />
    </application>
```

Mas información:

**[Declarar Activities en Manifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring)** (inglés).